# Error returned when using nested dictionary as lookup table for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that is used as a lookup table to assign a value to a dataframe field.
The code returns the following error when running:

TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", 'occurred at index 0')

I have tried using the get() function, yet receive the same error message.

The dictionary:

```py
AdjFact= {
        'Good':
            {0: 0, 2010: 2.566, 2011: 1.77, 2012: 0.9658515212},
        'Bad':
            {0: 0, 2010: 3.222, 2011: 1.0423, 2012: 0.3534},
        'Avg':
            {0: 0, 2010: 1.30, 2011: 4.2, 2012: 1.01}
            }
```

The code that looks for the value in the dictionary, uses a hardcoded value for the first dictionary value, and a value from a dataframe structure for the second dictionary value.
It saves the value that has been retrieved from the nested dictionary (using the Year value from the row in the dataframe) to the dataframe's row as a variable called AdjustedResult.

```
def lookup(row,lval):


    df= df_dict[[row['A'],row['B']]

    df['AdjustedResult'] = AdjFact[lval][df['Year']]


    . . . . . . . (more code deleted)
    return Total, Diff

newdf[['TotalGood' , 'DiffGood']] = newdf.apply(lookup, lval='Good', axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
newdf[['TotalBad' , 'DiffBad']] = newdf.apply(lookup, lval='Bad', axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
newdf[['TotalAvg' , 'DiffAvg']] = newdf.apply(lookup, lval='Avg', axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

I don't particularly have to use the AdjFact dictionary, if a different lookup table (dataframe, etc) would work.

**EDIT: added code below - just for testing purposes**

I have hardcoded in a lot of the values and dummy dataframes below, just so that the logic of the code can be tested (i.e. the lookup function)

```
import pandas as pd

new_df = pd.DataFrame({"RowNum": [1,2,3,4,5,6],"A": ['Test1','Test2','Test2','Test1','Test1','Test2'],
                       "B":['D','D','MO','D','D','D'],"Year": [2020,2008,2010,2008,2010,2011]})

df_dict_temp = {('Test1','D'): pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[3,2,4,5,2], "Year":[0,0,2010,2010,2011]}),
            ('Test2','D'):pd.DataFrame(),
            ('Test2','MO'):pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[3,2,4,5,2], "Year":[0,0,2010,2010,2011]})
            }

AdjFact= {
        'Good':
            {0: 0, 2010: 2.566, 2011: 1.77, 2012: 0.9658515212},
        'Bad':
            {0: 0, 2010: 3.222, 2011: 1.0423, 2012: 0.3534},
        'Avg':
            {0: 0, 2010: 1.30, 2011: 4.2, 2012: 1.01}
            }


def lookup(row,lval):


    m_df= df_dict_temp[row['A'],row['B']]

    m_df['AdjustedResult'] = AdjFact[lval][m_df['Year']]

    Total = 0
    #df['Discount'].sum()

    Diff = 0
    #df['Value'] - df['Discount']
    return Total, Diff

new_df[['TotalGood' , 'DiffGood']] = new_df.apply(lookup, lval='Good', axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['Year']` is a Series (which can't be hashed and therefore you can't look it up in a dict). I suspect you mean `row['Year']`, the year for that particular row?

That is,

```
df['AdjustedResult'] = AdjFact[lval][df['Year']]
```

should read:

```
df['AdjustedResult'] = AdjFact[lval][row['Year']]
```

--

Update: with your latest example, it seems you want to lookup the value for each row (I missed that in the first example):

```
ipdb> m_df['Year'].map(AdjFact[lval])
0    0.000
1    0.000
2    2.566
3    2.566
4    1.770
Name: Year, dtype: float64
```

So you should use:

```
m_df['AdjustedResult'] = m_df['Year'].map(AdjFact[lval])
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. No, I did not mean row['Year'], but I see I made a typo when posting the code (renamed the fields but forgot to rename all). The df['Year'] field contains the years to use in the dictionary lookup. The df dataframe is created in the function by passing the 2 of the row's fields as two keys to another dictionary (which I didn't post)

Comment: @SarahD df_dict[[row['A'],row['B']] is a DataFrame, did you mean to use .at ? e.g. df_dict.at[[row['A'],row['B']]

Comment: I'm very new to python, so I didn't know there was a .at function. That piece of code used to retrieve the df dataframe works - it is a two key dictionary (not nested). The piece of code used to retrieve the data from the nested dictionary (AdjFact) does not work :(

Comment: @SarahD can you amend your question so that I can run your code, if we can copy and paste into python/ipython and the error shows up we can more easily spot/fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added in dummy code below. The code contains hardcoded dataframes where in the actual code, this is read in through csv files.

Comment: @SarahD can you try with `m_df['AdjustedResult'] = m_df['Year'].map(AdjFact[lval].get)` ?

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked! I had used the map function previously when the dictionary was not nested, using this piece of code: m_df['AdjustedResult'] = m_df['Year'].map(lval). However, I had no idea how to do it once the requirements changed to a nested dict. If you have time, could you please explain the use of the get function here, though I will be googling it too :)

Comment: @SarahD oh turns out the .get is not necessary here (it used to be), .get is a dict method that looks up the value OR returns None (rather than `lambda x: d[x]` which would raise a KeyError if `x` is not in the d. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get